# Need, List of all Laravel -7 SQL error codes and descriptions

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I'am using Laravel-7 and MySQL.
I need the list of all exception and error code with php, laravel and SQL.

**For example-**

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
(SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = a@b.com)
```

In this case the error code 2002 means it refused the connection or database server not connected.

**Like this, I need all error code list with description.**

Where can I get this list ?

Comment: Go thru the source code for each module/library/etc and create a list.

Comment: You will probably find that you are looking for the MySQL error codes, try their site.

Comment: For what do you need them? What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I got the reference from MySQL official site. I provide the link below.

[MySQL error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/)